# Power Designer can not open file

Tags: powerdesigner

I have three logical design files. When I try to open them, Power designer throws an error message: Sybase power designer can not open the specified file. But there are no details at the error message so I can not understand what causes the problem and how can I fix it? Are there any log file of Power Designer about this issue? or do you know how can I open these files.

kind regards

Comment: It could be anything... Are the files in binary, or XML format? Any opportunity that they have been modified (manual edit of the file, copy by FTP without binary option...)? Which version of PowerDesigner are you using?